# Fetch data from big table based on big list of items

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have an ID list of 75000 records.Based on this I need to fetch corresponding items from another table which have 1700000+ records in c#. I tried with foreach and it taking 1+ hours.Both tables are in different servers. I tried contains in linq and it's not working. Please suggest me some better options.

```
 foreach(var item in cotext1.Table1)
 {
   var Employee=Context2.table2.where(x=>x.EmpId==item.Id);
 }
```

I tried to join, but getting out of memory exception.

Comment: What kind of database are we talking about here? Do you have control over the databases (can you, for instance, create procedures and user defined types)?

Comment: For Each? Do you mean that you are retrieving one record at time? Please show your code.(and of course you have an index on that second table for the column searched right?)

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes we have control over the db. We need to do it in C#.

Comment: @Steve yes , retrieving each record at a time now.

Comment: I think you should use a stored procedure and pass a table valued parameter as the comment of @ZoharPeled implies. Be sure that your indexes are correct also.

Comment: To do that fast you need to use table-valued variable and raw sql query (no entity framework). Then you just join your table-valued variable with target table on ID and select the results.

Comment: Can't we use any other method without using a stored procedure?I mean in c#?

Comment: You can use any method you want, but if you want to do it fast, then nothing beats good old stored procedures.

Comment: Stored procedure is not required, but table-valued variable is.

Comment: Even faster - store the 75K IDs in a temprorary table ensuring the ID column is indexed and join the two tables

Comment: @Evk AFAIK you can only use a table valued parameter with a stored procedure (or at least, you can't use it in "inline" sql).

Comment: without stored procedure but still without entity framework you can pass 75000 ids as xml string on manner <a><b>id1</b><b>id2</b>...<b>id75000</b></a> and  use sqlxml functions to convert it back to table and use join with this table declare 

`@x xml='<a><b>1</b><b>2</b><b>75000</b></a>';
select x.t.value('.[1]','int')from @x.nodes('/a/b') x(t);`

Comment: `tried with foreach and it taking 1+ hours` Please show us that code. [mcve]

Comment: @vitalygolub this is the worst possible solution. *And* far too cumbersome to write without stored procedures. Sprocs aren't bad or "legacy", just like functions in code or classes aren't bad or legacy. They are a way to tidy up complex queries

Comment: @ZoharPeled why not? You pass it as `SqlParameter` (like "@IDS") of SqlCommand the same way you would do with stored procedure, then you can use it in inline sql ("select * from MyTable A inner join @IDS B on ...").

Comment: @SinoyDevassy `fetch corresponding items from another table` why don't you join the two tables? Why do it in *C#*? Pulling data to the client and looping over it is **guaranteeed** to be orders of magnitude slower than performing the equivalent query. It could be N, it could be a lot worse

Comment: @SinoyDevassy you can use a linked server to combine data from both servers, or, better yet, pull the data from the other server and put it in a staging table

Comment: @SinoyDevassy in any case, what you ask is an ETL job. ORMs like EF are unsuitable for ETL jobs - there are no *objects* to map in such jobs, just data to pull, transform and store

Comment: Fetch 75000 ids from server 1 (that is one query). Create a temporary table on server 2 and insert 75000 rows in there (that is still one query but you need to build it using C# code). Join temporary table to the other table and fetch results.

Comment: @Evk I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify what was discussed in comments:

1. Create user defined type which corresponds to your list with IDs (since it doesn't make sense for ids to repeat in your list - I made it primary key):

   ```
   CREATE TYPE dbo.IntHashSet AS TABLE 
   (
       ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
   )
   ```
2. Query:

   ```
   using (var ctx = new TestDBEntities()) {
       // fill data table with your ids
       var dt = new DataTable();
       dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));                    
       for (int i = 0; i < 75000; i++) {
          dt.Rows.Add(i);
       }
       // make a query
       var result = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<BigTable>("select BT.* from BigTable BT inner join @IDS I on BT.CodeID = I.ID",
           new SqlParameter("IDS", SqlDbType.Structured)
           {                        
               // name of type you created in step 1
               TypeName = "dbo.IntHashSet",
               Value = dt
           }).ToArray();
   }
   ```

This query with 75.000 ids against table with 1.700.000 rows takes about 600ms on my (non-server, consumer grade) machine. Which is several orders of magnituge faster than what it takes now with your query (more than one hour).

Comment: Is there any confirmation that OP is using SqlServer?

Comment: @IvanStoev not really, I just had such implession. But if that will not be the case, I will either update answer for OPs database or delete it if that will be database I have no idea how to do that for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join statement in linq

```
    Server1Entities dc1 = new Server1Entities ();
    List<IDTable> ids = (from ro in dc1.IDTable select ro).ToList();

    Server2Entities dc2 = new Server2Entities();

    var list = (from firstTable in ids
                join secondTable in dc.YourSecondTable
                on firstTable.ID equals secondTable.ID
                select new {

                 field1 = firstTable.Field1,
                 field2 = secondTableField1 // You can define fieldnames as you want.
                }).ToList();
```

Another option is using the morelinq library. Really extraordinary. 
you can take a look :

https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ

Comment: Is is a question about database queries. If both sets of ID exist in the same database there's *no* reason to pull the IDs to the client just to send them back to the server. If the IDs exist only on the client side (eg a file with IDs) LINQ can't make client-side IDs appear on the server by magic. *If* that query works at all, it will have to create a giant `IN ()` clause or use TVPs. `IN` has a limit so it may not work

Comment: He says that "Both tables are in different servers".

Comment: In this case, the asnwer is linked servers. Or temporary staging tables. With 75K you stretch the limits of the IN clause. A TVP results in execution plans that favor small amounts of data

Comment: That is why I said that he can try morelinq library. I tried it before in bigger tables, it is extremly performant.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos surprisingly similar query (if use `List<int>` instead of `List<IDTable>`) will work, at least in latest EF versions, and will generate inner join with giant UNION ALL clause (instead of IN).

Comment: @Evk there's a difference between "will work" and "work well". This is an ETL job, not an ORM query

Comment: @CoskunOzogul and MoreLinq has nothing to do with databases either. "Bigger Tables" means millions of rows. 75K rows is no data worth mentioning. ORMs are unsuitable for ETL jobs